# Extreme point theorem of linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

So I was told to find a counterexample to this linear programming extreme point theorem:

"If $S$ is nonempty and not bounded and if an optimal solution to the problem exists, then an optimal solution occurs at an extreme point."

Is there any hint? Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Main idea: Follow the gradient to find an optimum. This is possible because the feasible area is convex. Now imagine as feasible area something like a rectangle with infinite length to the right.

Comment: Would you like to explain "the gradient"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient
The gradient of the function to be optimized points into the direction of fastest increase.